# What defines a duplicate, a question or its description?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicates

There have been countless questions on this subject, but the closest one I found was about (something like) what defines a duplicate, the question or the answer? This one is slightly different.

I ran into [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463238/how-to-run-command-at-startup/463280#463280). I saw the question was mentioned as a duplicate to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270049/how-to-run-a-command-at-login) in a comment, and started happily writing an answer in the supposed original.

Then I looked better into the exact words of the *description* of he question and read that the poster explicitly asked for a solution that also worked without GUI log in. Since my answer (not a duplicate as far as I can see) only works when logging in *with* GUI, I felt silly posting it there, and came to the conclusion that although the *question* seemed to be a duplicate, the *description* of the question asked for a different solution. Therefore it could not be an exact duplicate. I have seen other examples like this, where questions were happily closed as duplicate, while indeed the *title* suggested a duplicate, but the description made clear the origin of the question was different.

My question is in general, since in this case there was still another duplicate that I overlooked, which *was* a real duplicate in my opinion.

So my question is: what defines a duplicate, a question, its description or both?

Comment: Aha, an epistemology question!  I'm glad there's already an accepted answer. ;)

Comment: @belacqua I had to look it up :). I think strictly practiced rules should be clearly defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The complete question consists of the *Title* and the *Text*. While we want the title to be formulated as question (which rarely happens), the text is not merely the *Description* as you put it.

So a question can only be regarded as a duplicate of another one if the complete questions (i.e. Title **and** Text) meet that criterion.

Comment: I think asking the question makes clear this is the answer I was hoping for. In practice, in the triangle of question, description and answer, we should be careful marking a question as duplicate too easily. I have also recently seen examples in which the *question* was marked as duplicate as a result of an  *answer*, drifting away from the question in the direction of a duplicate, while the question was not. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @JacobVlijm You bring up here another point: assessing a question as duplicate because (although the question looks different) the answers have to be the same - in that case I would rather point to the question with the good answers - and vote for *duplicate*.

Comment: I don't mean the answer *should* be the same, but the *perception* of the question is set by the emphasis in an answer. Example: http://askubuntu.com/questions/461597/why-do-commented-lines-in-a-linux-configuration-file-sometimes-work/461611#461611 Look at Braiam's version (3rd edit, the clearest qua meaning IMO) which makes clear the poster *knows* that it is a shebang, but simply wonders why the # is not making the line ignored. Actually different from the supposed original. The answer however bends the question towards the duplicate, and it was marked as such. Not justly I think.